# Why Data on YouTube's Feeds is different than real Data?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Try yourself : as example, try to retrieve the fields of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcQ-V9nFZgs) video : you will see "published on 27/nov/2011" on the page.

But, retrieving the XML by Youtube API with http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads/?start-index=1&max-results=1
the XML returned is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007'>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads</id>
  <updated>2011-12-05T15:26:39.146Z</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
  <title type='text'>Uploads by zimbarvideo</title>
  <logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
  <link rel='related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo'/>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=zimbarvideo#p/u'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads/batch'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads?start-index=1&amp;max-results=1'/>
  <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads?start-index=2&amp;max-results=1'/>
  <author>
    <name>zimbarvideo</name>
    <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version='2.1' uri='http://gdata.youtube.com'>YouTube data API</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>274</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>1</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/lcQ-V9nFZgs</id>
    <published>2011-11-28T07:21:41.000Z</published>
    <updated>2011-11-28T15:33:45.000Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' term='News' label='Notizie e politica'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='progetto'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='continuità'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='bilinguismo'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' term='precoce'/>
    <title type='text'>285 - TG Cimbro - Zimbar Earde - Luserna</title>
    <content type='text'>Zimbar Earde 285 del 26/11/2011
      Inaugurazione scuola "progetto continuità -- bilinguismo precoce" "khlummane tritt vürsnen"  
      interv. a Luca Paolaz, Anna Maria Trenti Kaufman, Sieghart Camper, Monica Pedrazza, Ermenegildo Bidese.
      È attivo dal 26/11/11 "Sostegno ai compiti" sab 10.00-12.00 in Biblioteca
      L'istituto Ladino di Livinallongo/Santa Lucia in visita al KIL (19/11/2011)
      Appuntamenti e  invito alla Festa piano giovani degli Altipiani ai Virti - 3/12/2011</content>
      <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcQ-V9nFZgs&amp;feature=youtube_gdata'/>
      <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/lcQ-V9nFZgs/responses'/>
      <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/lcQ-V9nFZgs/related'/>
      <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile' type='text/html' href='http://m.youtube.com/details?v=lcQ-V9nFZgs'/>
      <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo/uploads/lcQ-V9nFZgs'/>
      <author>
        <name>zimbarvideo</name>
        <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/zimbarvideo</uri>
      </author>
      <gd:comments>
        <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/lcQ-V9nFZgs/comments' countHint='0'/>
      </gd:comments>
      <media:group>
        <media:category label='Notizie e politica' scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>News</media:category>
        <media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/lcQ-V9nFZgs?version=3&amp;f=user_uploads&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='771' yt:format='5'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v3.cache5.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwkLZsXZVz7ElRMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='771' yt:format='1'/>
        <media:content url='rtsp://v8.cache4.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwkLZsXZVz7ElRMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='771' yt:format='6'/>
        <media:description type='plain'>Zimbar Earde 285 del 26/11/2011
          Inaugurazione scuola "progetto continuità -- bilinguismo precoce" "khlummane tritt vürsnen"  
          interv. a Luca Paolaz, Anna Maria Trenti Kaufman, Sieghart Camper, Monica Pedrazza, Ermenegildo Bidese.
          È attivo dal 26/11/11 "Sostegno ai compiti" sab 10.00-12.00 in Biblioteca
          L'istituto Ladino di Livinallongo/Santa Lucia in visita al KIL (19/11/2011)
          Appuntamenti e  invito alla Festa piano giovani degli Altipiani ai Virti - 3/12/2011</media:description>
          <media:keywords>progetto, continuità, bilinguismo, precoce</media:keywords>
          <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcQ-V9nFZgs&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcQ-V9nFZgs/0.jpg' height='360' width='480' time='00:06:25.500'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcQ-V9nFZgs/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:03:12.750'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcQ-V9nFZgs/2.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:06:25.500'/>
          <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/lcQ-V9nFZgs/3.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:09:38.250'/>
          <media:title type='plain'>285 - TG Cimbro - Zimbar Earde - Luserna</media:title>
          <yt:duration seconds='771'/>
        </media:group>
        <yt:statistics favoriteCount='0' viewCount='23'/>
      </entry>
    </feed>
```

which it doesnt contain at all 2011-11-27, neither on Data fields :

```
<published>2011-11-28T07:21:41.000Z</published>
<updated>2011-11-28T15:33:45.000Z</updated>
```

So, what's wrong with YouTube's API?

Comment: Time zones, for one. `Z` is zulu/utc/GMT. If you're in GMT-8, then it'd show a publication date of Nov 27th.

Comment: So how can I convert it?

Comment: Tried with `video.Updated.ToUniversalTime()` but still doenst works... (it prints 28/11/2011 15.33.45  instead of 28/11/2011 16.33.45 (so just an hour...not a day)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time zone for uploaded date (on the page) and the published date (gdata feed) are different. The former is PST, the latter is UTC.